# Как лучше реализовать описание в картинной галерее начиная с "catalog no" до "category"?

Tags: html, css

[image: Галерея]

Как порекомендуете сделать описание? в виде таблицы или блоками?

Comment: Это явно табличный контент, так что в виде таблицы.

Answer (score 3):

Приветствую. Была схожая задача, отлично с этим в оформлении справился description list. Как пример: https://getuikit.com/docs/description-list#description-list

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать тег, который создан для создания списка определений:

```css
dl {
  margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
dt {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  text-align:left;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight:bold;
}
dd {
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<div class="price">$ 0,000.00</div>
<p>Описание</p>
<dl>
 <dt>Характеристика</dt>
 <dd>Описание</dd>
 <dt>Характеристика</dt>
 <dd>Описание</dd>
 <dt>Характеристика</dt>
 <dd>Описание</dd>
</dl>
```